# I want to change background color of icons on every route in header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, routes

I have 6 icons in header I want to change background color of active icon. But onClick is performing navigation as well so I have to double click on an icon to change color. I have searched but all I can find examples using Link but I have useNavigation. How can I do that?

here's my code

```
<Button
    style={clickedButton === 'home' ? { backgroundColor:'#D3D3D3' } : {}}
    color="inherit"
    onClick={() => {
    handleButtonClick('home')
    navigate("/home")
  }}>
       <HomeIcon />
</Button>

<Button
   style={clickedButton === 'btn2' ? { backgroundColor: '#D3D3D3' } : {}}
   color="inherit"
   onClick={() => {
   handleButtonClick('btn2')
   navigate("/next-page")
  }}>
     <DocumentScannerIcon />
```

`
It works fine for home as it doesn't navigate but for other icons it works on double click

Comment: Why don't you just use the `active` CSS selector? You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active).

Comment: I'm using MUI button and styled components for styling how can I use active with that?

Answer (score 0):

for your answer i have a code will help you  .

**Note**: I use @emotion/styled for styling

Route Config File:

```
import DashboardIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DashboardSharp";
import PeopleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PeopleSharp";
import { OverridableComponent } from "@mui/material/OverridableComponent";
import { SvgIconTypeMap } from "@mui/material/SvgIcon";

export default [
  { path: "/admin/dashboard", name: "Dashboard", icon: DashboardIcon },
  { path: "/admin/users", name: "Users", icon: PeopleIcon },
] as RouteConfig[];

export type RouteConfig = {
  path: string;
  name: string;
  icon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & {
    muiName: string;
  };
};
```

NavBar File:

```
import { IconButton, MenuItem, MenuList } from "@mui/material";
import routeConfig from "../../shared/route.config";
import LogoutIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PowerSettingsNewOutlined";

import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
type Props = {
  onClick?: () => void;
};
export default function MenuListAdminComponent(props: Props) {
  const route = useRouter();
  return (
    <MenuListAdminComponentStyle>
      <MenuList id="menu">
        {routeConfig.map((res) => (
          <MenuItem
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              borderRadius: 6,
            }}
            key={res.path}
            onClick={() => {
              if (props.onClick) {
                props.onClick();
              }
              route.replace(res.path);
            }}
          >
            {
              <res.icon
                id={res.path.includes(route.pathname) ? "active" : "notActive"}
              />
            }
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </MenuList>
      <div id="exit">
        <IconButton>
          <LogoutIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
    </MenuListAdminComponentStyle>
  );
}
const MenuListAdminComponentStyle = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  #menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 20px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    svg {
      color: #959595;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    #active {
      color: #7942fb;
    }
  }
  #exit {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
`;
```